# React - Store updated but didnt re-render the Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

The scenario is :
1.press a button(Class A-Component) to add a item to a list (Class B-Component) then re-render the Table.

I have checked the list in the store by store.getState() And i have updated the list in the store perfectly after pressing button.

**But it didnt re render the Table which showing the list.**

Anyone can help ?

**initialState3**

```
var initialState3 = {
  products1: [
    {
      id: "123",
      abbreviation: "123",
      case_no: "123",
      created_dt: "31/01/2018",
      last_updated: "11:43:45"
    }
  ]
};
```

**reducers**

```
function ReducersForSeach(state = initialState3, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CLICK_SEARCH": {
      products1.push({
        id: "456",
        abbreviation: "456",
        case_no: "456",
        created_dt: "31/01/2018",
        last_updated: "11:43:45"
      });

      return {
        ...state,
        products1
      };
    }
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
var Table = React.createClass({
  render() {
    const { products1 } = this.props;
    const tableHeaderColumns = columnData.map(column => (
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField={column.action} isKey={column.isKey} dataSort={column.dataSort}>
        {column.description}
      </TableHeaderColumn>
    ));

    return (
      <BootstrapTable height="600" style={{ overflowY: "scroll" }} data={products1} options={options}>
        {tableHeaderColumns}
      </BootstrapTable>
    );
  }
});
```

**Connection**

```
function mapStateToPropsFortable(state) {
  return {
    products1: state.reducreForSeach.products1
  };
}

const Table1 = connect(
  mapStateToPropsFortable,
  null
)(Table);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Table1 />
  </Provider>,

  document.getElementById("divReqListTable")
);
```

**Store**

```
var rootReducer = Redux.combineReducers({
  reducreForAge,
  reducreForButtonGroup2,
  reducreForSeach
});

var store = Redux.createStore(rootReducer);
```

Comment: Have you tired with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Chang your reducer to this**

```
function ReducersForSeach(state = initialState3, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CLICK_SEARCH": {
      const products1 = {
        id: "456",
        abbreviation: "456",
        case_no: "456",
        created_dt: "31/01/2018",
        last_updated: "11:43:45"
      };
      return {
        ...state,
        products1: state.products1.concat(products1)
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

You click try it in https://codesandbox.io/embed/74108xyln0

Comment: concat returns 'array', using array to wrap an array will result in nested array! this will not solve the problem

Comment: i have tried ur code , after dispatching the action , Both of the list in store and the UI didnt update :/ still remaining one item in the list

Comment: only the reducer in my question , can add item to store :(

Comment: @OliverCheng, I've configured pretty much like your app in sandbox and it work fine. please try it  https://codesandbox.io/embed/74108xyln0

Comment: THx  Kyaw Kyaw Soe  i saw ur example on sandbox  , its works but still didnt work on my app . i will look into it . thankyou so much!!!

Comment: @OliverCheng appreciate to help, if the answer correct or help please click accept.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem area.

```
return {
    ...state,
    products1
  };
```

Change this line function `ReducersForSeach(state = initialState3, action) {` to

```
function ReducersForSeach(state = initialState3.products1, action) {
```

Comment: just change this single line => function state = initialState3.products1??
how about the  problem area?? THX

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
products1 = {
  id: "456",
  abbreviation: "456",
  case_no: "456",
  created_dt: "31/01/2018",
  last_updated: "11:43:45"
});

return {
  ...state,
  products1: [...state.products1, products1]
};
```

Normally you would put the payload in there and send through that object when you are dispatching the action.

Like this::

```
return {
  ...state,
  products: [...state.products, action.payload]
};
```

This is assuming that `products` is an array and you want to `.push()` a new item into that array.

I hope this helps. :)

**UPDATE::**
Here is a full example of the reducer that i use for products, that adds a new one in every time it's called.
I do send the object through in the action.

Reducer:

```
import {
    PRODUCTS,
} from '../constants/ActionTypes';

let products = []
if (localStorage.getItem('products') != undefined) {
  products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'))
}

const initialState = {
  products: products
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCTS:
      localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify([...state.items, action.payload]))
      return {
        ...state,
        products: [...state.items, action.payload]
      }
      break;
    default:
      // console.log('Products reducer called: default');
      // console.log(action.type);
      break;
  }
  return state
}
```

action::

```
export const addProduct = (obj) => {
  return {
    type: PRODUCTS,
    payload: obj
  };
};
```

This is the action call in the index.js file.

```
this.props.dispatch(addProduct(newItemObj));
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: i have tried ur code , after dispatching the action , the list in store didnt update :/ still  remaining one item in the list

Comment: @OliverCheng just made an update of how I make it work. that might help